# How do i remove an instantiated Spotify Web Playback SDK player?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spotify

My current problem is that every time a user starts a new "game", a spotify web playback sdk player is instantiated, which is as intended. However i can't seem to wrap my head around how i should "disconnect" or remove the web player from their spotify account, when the user either clicks out of the game or closes the tab(This is also a problem im currently facing, because i need to handle removing a user mid-game)

So any leads to how i A) remove an instantiated spotify web playback sdk player, so the users spotify wont get filled with them and B) how should i handle removing these. how do i listen to closing a tab etc.

I've tried the `addEventListener("unload", (event) => {});` but im unsure whether this is does what i intend(handles code when user leaves your page)